# MySQL query - help for improvements

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have this query to perform:

```
SELECT u1.firstname,
       u1.lastname,
       u1.totalcommission,
       u1.userid,
       count(DISTINCT u2.userid) AS level1,
       count(DISTINCT u3.userid) AS level2
FROM users AS u1
INNER JOIN users AS u2 ON u1.userid = u2.affiliate1
AND u2.signupdate BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-02 23:59:59'
LEFT JOIN users AS u3 ON u1.userid = u3.affiliate2
WHERE u1.usertypeid != '1'
GROUP BY u1.userid
ORDER BY count(DISTINCT u2.userid) DESC
```

The indexes of the table:

```
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  userid  41318   A   No  
email   BTREE   Yes No  email   41318   A   No  
affiliate1  BTREE   No  No  affiliate1  1967    A   Yes 
affiliate2  BTREE   No  No  affiliate2  258 A   Yes 
signupdate  BTREE   No  No  signupdate  41318   A   No
```

The query works, but the problem is that is really slow (the table users has 43k rows, no more), it takes around 10sec, due to the count(distinct) functions. Is there a way to replace it with something more performing?

Thanks,

/Luca

Comment: an you post the structures of all the tables? what are the indexes on the table?

Comment: Could you add "DESC " before the query and add the output of that query to your question? That query will show you where and which keys are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting clobbered due to some unexpected Cartesian results.  I would try the following.  Since your first inner join is based on affiliate1 entries must exist, I would pre-aggregate those to get 1 record per affiliate where the affiliate's ID joins back to the user table and only gets those where user type != '1'.  This basically creates your count DISTINCT for you.  Then, join to the user table to get the user information FOR THIS affiliate.  Then, do a left-join similar, but for the 2nd affiliate (if any such exist... also based on affiliate's user type != '1').

Now, you'll have at MAX a 1:1 ratio per table and should be very quick.

```
SELECT 
      u1.firstname,
      u1.lastname,
      u1.totalcommission,
      u1.userid,
      PreAggUA1.AffiliateUsers as Level1,
      PreAggUA2.AffiliateUsers as Level2
   FROM 
      ( select 
              ua1.affiliate1,
              count(*)  as AffiliateUsers
           from users ua1
              join users ua1b
                  on ua1.affiliate1 = ua1b.userid
                 and ua1b.userTypeID != '1'
              group by
                 ua1.affiliate1 ) as PreAggUA1

         JOIN Users u1
            on PreAggUA1.Affiliate1 = u1.UserID

         LEFT JOIN ( select 
                           ua2.affiliate2,
                           count(*)  as AffiliateUsers
                        from 
                           users ua2
                              join users ua2b
                                 on ua2.affiliate2 = ua2b.userid
                                and ua2b.userTypeID != '1'
                         group by
                            ua2.affiliate2 ) as PreAggUA2
            on PreAggUA1.Affiliate1 = PreAggUA2.Affiliate2
   ORDER BY 
      PreAggUA1.AffiliateUsers DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already grouping by user_id and than counting it to order. Alternatively you can simple order it using DESC with group by

```
SELECT
  u1.firstname,
  u1.lastname,
  u1.totalcommission,
  u1.userid,
  count( distinct u2.userid ) AS level1,
  count( distinct u3.userid ) AS level2
FROM users AS u1
  INNER JOIN users AS u2
    ON u1.userid = u2.affiliate1
  INNER JOIN users AS u3
    ON u1.userid = u3.affiliate2
WHERE u1.usertypeid != '1'
    and u2.signupdate between '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
    and '2013-04-02 23:59:59'
GROUP BY u1.userid DESC , u2.userid , u3.userid
```

Comment: Thanks...unfortunately this query still takes 10 seconds

Comment: Thanks...this way you eliminate at least one count distinct, and this is good, but it's still slow (9 sec). Do you know a way to replace the other count(distinct)?

Comment: i have updated the query again. For your information when you are using aggregate function on a column use group by that coulmn which will increase the performance

Comment: Thanks raheel but it will not work this way I think....level1 and level2 will always be set as "1", losing the data I need.